# .Net Core 2.0 replacement for HttpResponseBase

Tags: c#, json, http

I am porting some code from an old MVC 5 app to a Core 2.0 app.

The SerializeData method is failing as HttpResponseBase is no longer in Core 2.0 and I can't seem to find a suitable replacement in any of the Core libraries. Resharper not even detecting the proper library to add as a dependency.

```
private void SerializeData(HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        if (ErrorMessages.Any())
        {
            Data = new
            {
                ErrorMessage = string.Join("\n", ErrorMessages),
                ErrorMessages = ErrorMessages.ToArray()
            };
            response.StatusCode = 400;
        }
        if (Data == null) return;
        response.Write(Data.ToJson());
        {
        }
    }

public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static string ToJson<T>(this T obj, bool includeNull = true)
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
            Converters = new JsonConverter[] { new StringEnumConverter() },
            NullValueHandling = includeNull ? NullValueHandling.Include : NullValueHandling.Ignore
        };
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings);
    }
}
```

Comment: What you can try is: 
For the statuscode 400 use 
var badRequest = BadRequest();
and for the Data, looks like an object:
try 
var objectData = Json(Data);

hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference the following package:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResponse;
```

And change `HttpResponseBase` to `HttpResponse`:

```
private void SerializeData(HttpResponse response)
```

Comment: @ceferrari...is there somewhere, that you know of, to go to find a list of all the asp.net libraries? Would make searching for answers much easier

Comment: Take a look at the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`. If you create a new `Core` web project it will be referenced automatically